# Are the ejected first stage Electron rocket batteries really incinerated?

Tags: launch, rocketlab, electron, battery

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33449/12102) reminded me that the Electron rocket drops one of it's batteries when it is mostly spent. We might call that "micro-staging".

This [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24571/12102) quotes [Spaceflight 101](http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/electron/):

> With a low auto-ignition temperature of only 150°C, the second stage batteries will burn up in their entirety during re-entry **while the first stage batteries are also likely to be incinerated to some extent** during their sub-orbital re-entry.

The phrase "...likely to be incinerated to some extent..." is a bit vague and half-hearted.

Is there any further information on this? Do they hit the water in burning lithium and plastic flames, or do they dissipate before impact?

Comment: New Zealand changed or at least assessed it's law to allow for rocketlab launches: [Regulatory Impact Statement: Regulation of deposit of jettisoned material from space vehicle launches under the Exclusive Economic Zone and Continental Shelf (Environmental Effects) Act2012](https://www.mfe.govt.nz/sites/default/files/media/Legislation/RIS/ris-jettisoned-material-space-launch-28-feb-final.pdf). It also mentions batteries impact on the ocean. Citation: "Information from Rocket Lab notes that lithium batteries are expected to burn up completely during  descent rather than be deposited.".

Comment: @Christoph thanks for that! "...expected to burn up completely..." is definitely different than "...likely to be incinerated to some extent..." Hmm... I wonder if they are telling different stories to different people!?

Comment: @uhoh It seems impossible that the first-stage batteries burn up during their descent. By definition, they're jettinosed well before MECO. In this launch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNuauG1Gvr8,  at MECO the Electron rocket was at an altitude of 77.8 km; jettisoning must have happened well before that. This article http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/electron/ states that the used batteries have an auto-ignition temperature of 150° C; it seems not sure at all that this temperature is reached, by atmospheric friction, during a fall from some tens of kilometers.

Comment: @JanvanOort thanks, but I think you are mostly just reiterating the content of the question.

Comment: @uhoh I was trying to (begin to) stick some numbers on it, though :-)

Comment: @JanvanOort okay, 150C is already in the question, and "well below 77.8 km" isn't a number yet. ;-) I think the altitude of the battery hot-swap event can be obtained from some of the Rocketlabs launch videos, they sometimes announce the event, and I think I've actually seen one drop in one of the videos.

Comment: @JanvanOort oh wait, I'm thinking of the stage 2 battery drops for the "hot-swap" in the video, see [What was ejected from RocketLab's Electron launch vehicle at T+6:25 during stage two burn?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24570/12102) Now I don't think I've seen a first stage battery drop in a video.

Comment: @uhoh you're completely right; that's a second-stage (at T+6:25 it can't be but that).

Comment: @JanvanOort They'll hit harder than simply free-fall from the jettison altitude.  Rockets also have horizontal velocity--enough that SpaceX learned the hard way they had to do a burn before entering the atmosphere or the booster would be damaged.

Answer (score 6):

The question turns out to be a bit misguided as the first stage batteries are *not* ejected during flight; however, it can still be answered **no.**

Spaceflight 101's quality can be mediocre at times. I think this article is an example of that.

I found no evidence that states that the first stage batteries are dumped overboard during flight. The [Electron Payload User's Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20220108061833/https://www.rocketlabusa.com/assets/Uploads/Payload-User-Guide-LAUNCH-V6.6.pdf) explicitly states this for the *second stage* (emphasis added):

> High Voltage Batteries (HVBs) batteries provide power to the LOx and kerosene pumps [...] During the second stage burn, two HVBs power the electric pumps until depletion, when a third HVB takes over for the remainder of the second stage burn. **Upon depletion, the first two HVBs are jettisoned from Electron to reduce mass and increase performance in flight.**

There is no such statement for the first stage. Additionally, looking at the layout of the vehicle in various pictures I see no clear mechanism for ejecting the first stage batteries short of also jettisoning all 9 engines. From the [User's Guide](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/assets/Uploads/Payload-User-Guide-LAUNCH-V6.6.pdf#page=11) the batteries (power pack) are located between the tanks and engines, probably *around* the engine plumbing:
[image: first stage power pack]

Close up pictures don't seem to show anything either from the bottom or side:
[image: close up 1]

Credit: Rocket Lab, from [Spaceflight 101](https://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/electron/)

[image: close up 2]

Credit: Rocket Lab, from [Spaceflight Now article](https://spaceflightnow.com/2018/01/21/rocket-lab-delivers-nanosatellites-to-orbit-on-first-successful-test-launch/)

[image: close up 3]

Credit: Rocket Lab, from [Engadget article](https://www.engadget.com/rocket-lab-will-test-its-parachute-system-on-a-live-booster-for-the-first-time-160020286.html)

The incineration part is basically [DOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_on_arrival#Colloquial_use) because we know that Rocket Lab is pursuing [recovery and eventual re-use of the Electron booster](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/updates/rocket-lab-announces-reusability-plans-for-electron-rocket/). They [have already fished-out a flown booster](https://twitter.com/RocketLab/status/1461412933703897091?cxt=HHwWhsCo-b_U_ccoAAAA) and because the batteries remain onboard they are not exposed to the heat of re-entry.

The main concern for Rocket Lab is the [heating on the engines](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/updates/rocket-lab-to-recover-electron-booster-on-next-mission/#:%7E:text=Because%20Electron%20will%20enter%20the%20atmosphere%20engines%20first%2C%20the%20nine%203D%20printed%20Rutherford%20engines%20on%20the%20first%20stage%20will%20bear%20the%20brunt%20of%20this%20extreme%20heating.%20To%20withstand%20the%20immense%20temperatures%2C%20this%20Electron%20features%20an%20evolved%20heat%20shield%20designed%20to%20protect%20the%20engines) and they make no mention of protecting the power pack. I suspect that there is very little heat transferred to the batteries during the brief, but [fiery re-entry](https://www.rocketlabusa.com/updates/rocket-lab-confirms-helicopter-capture-attempt-for-next-recovery-mission/#:%7E:text=Improvements%20to%20the%20launch%20vehicle%20for%20this%20next%20recovery%20attempt%20will%20include%20a%20thermal%20protection%20system%20applied%20to%20the%20entire%20stage%20and%20its%20nine%20Rutherford%20engines%20to%20help%20it%20endure%20heat%20of%20up%20to%202%2C400%20degrees%20Celsius%20during%20re%2Dentry%2C) period. Additionally, [the toxic flames of burning batteries](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jhazmat.2019.120916) could damage electrical connectors (among countless other things) and would also be a risk to humans involved in any recovery operations (and protective instruments are not seen in limited pictures).

This screenshot from [Everyday Astronaut's Rocket Lab tour video](https://youtu.be/-VGZ8DGkiyc?t=131) appears to confirm the radial battery placement and definitely shows just how impregnated they are inside the vehicle:

[image: technician working on power pack]

It also shows the individual "battery units" covered in (presumably) some kind of [multi-layer insulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-layer_insulation). Batteries [have some of the strictest temperature limits of all space hardware (slide 5)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-851-satellite-engineering-fall-2003/lecture-notes/l23thermalcontro.pdf)*. Such tight limits necessitates ample engineering effort towards their thermal control.

*this table is likely referring to older nickel based space batteries, but lithium based batteries still have tight limits.